# Decoding .rgb file into readable image data?

Tags: images, format, rgb

I've extracted some image assets out of a popular Simpsons game but I can't find any application to read or convert them, and I'm not even sure what format they are in, besides for their .rgb extension. A sample file is located at: http://ge.tt/9bn1yiE/v/0 and I was hoping someone would be able to figure it out...

P.S. I've already tried Mac OS X Preview, Gimp, dcraw, without success.

Comment: Looks like it could be raw RGB data without a header. This is supported by the file length being evenly divisible by `3` I.e. `4488/3 == 1496`.

Comment: Couldn't make the link work.

Comment: I found http://gimpforums.com/thread-reading-raw-image-data-not-camera-raw and it helped me decode the splash screen, etc. but the images like those above don't decode the colours properly. It looks like the images have been generated by Adobe Flash for iOS, if that helps at all/

Comment: Using gimp raw data (see the comment from Adam M-W), it seems indexed RGB data of a 64x70 picture.